# Exception in thread "Timer-0" thrown when run the application

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, spring-security, glassfish

When I run my application it works but throws exceptions in console as following:
Every time it shows a different timer number. All technologies that I used are tagged for the question. Please let me know if you need me to share any other part of my code apart from following.

```
    SEVERE:   Exception in thread "Timer-0"
SEVERE:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1652)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkIdleResources(BasicResourcePool.java:1481)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$2000(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CheckIdleResourcesTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1964)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
    public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            System.err.println("in session Facotry");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            return configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(
                    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                    .build());
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some context. There is very little we can do with what you've provided.

Comment: what do you mean by context? I am not sue what causes the exception and I have listed all of the technologies I am using.

Comment: It's the line below that matters

Comment: You seem to be using a connection pool that is involved with your web app. Show us how it is configured. Show us any other logs your web application is producing.

Comment: Question is updated guys, thanks

Comment: Post a full stacktrace.

Comment: Is your code creating timers anywhere?

Comment: I will also add that if you're using Glassfish or any other full stack application server then there's better ways of configuring Hibernate. Consider defining a DataSource in Glassfish and wiring that into your application by passing it's JNDI name in the hibernate.connection.datasource property. You can then manage the connection pool using Glassfish facilities without needing 3rd party libraries. You can then git rid of the first 4 hibernate.connection properties and all of the c3p0 configuration.

Comment: @SteveC thanks for your explanation, No I have not defined any timer . how about if I use tomcat is that the same ? should I keep the DataSource in it?

Comment: You can define datasources in Tomcat too

Comment: @RomanC the full stacktrace is included in the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is the c3p0 connection pooling library attempting to do connection maintenance before the server has completed it's startup process.

The use of a 3rd party connection pooling mechanism is redundant on a full stack Java EE server such as Glassfish, WildFly/JBossAS, WebLogic, etc.

The solution is to

1. remove all c3p0 related jars from your application (and any you may have added to the application server)
2. Define a datasource in glassfish with the connection details as per your hibernate configuration
3. Reduce your hibernate configuration properties to:

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jndi name of the datasource you defined in step 2</property>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
   <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

   <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
   <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
   ```

Note that Tomcat supports the use of DataSources and has it's own connection pooling implementation as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer, may I know when I should use c3p0? and why is c3p0 attempt to do connection maintenance before the server has completed it's startup process? Please also not some times this error is thrown while application is running.

Comment: You might use c3p0 if your application was something designed to run standalone, rather than in a Java EE hosted environment. I've never used c3p0 so I cannot explain it's behaviour.

Comment: By standalone, I mean your application is not running in any application server such as JBossAS/WildFly or Tomcat.

Comment: @SteveC c3p0 is used in the production environment, it worth to have it applicable if you install it to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

do you use any other static initialization blocks other than in HibernateUtil.class ? and for testing change all exception in HibernateUtil and catch Throwable instead.

it seems like the error happened during initializing of your web application and all static initialization blocks.

Comment: no there is not any other static, I suspect the problem is caused by hibernate configuration as I recently changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is called from a background task, whose job is to cleanup resources and it had started prior to having the server fully initialized.

This is not a problem cause by your code, it looks like Glassfish jobs are not following the right execution order.

I'd advise you to file an issue report on [Glassfish issue tracker](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH) and provide them:

- app server version
- OS version
- app config files

Comment: what do you think about Steve C's answer?

Comment: I think he's right. Up-voted his response. In JEE you should use the DS provided by the AS, since those are managed by the transaction manager.